# How to retrieve a value from <input> using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to hidden input fields such as:

```
<input name="foo" value="bar">
<input name="foo1" value="bar1">
```

I'd like to retrieve both of those values and POST them to the server using jQuery. How does one use the jQuery selector engine to grab those values?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As "foo" and "foo1" are the *name* of you input fields, you will not be able to use the id selector of jQuery (#), but you'll have to use instead the attribute selector :

```
var foo = $("[name='foo']").val();
var foo1 = $("[name='foo1']").val();
```

That's not the best option, performance-wise. You'd better set the id of your input fields and use the id selector (e.g. $("#foo")) or at least provide a context to the attribute selector:

```
var form = $("#myForm"); // or $("form"), or any selector matching an element containing your input fields
var foo = $("[name='foo']", form).val();
var foo1 = $("[name='foo1']", form).val();
```

Comment: They may not perform as well as $('#foo'), but unless it's a problem, don't worry about it. Premature optimization and all that.

Comment: @Andrew, you're completely right, users wouldn't see the difference in most cases. It's more a best practice, especially considering that the name might not be unique.

Comment: Alternatively you may access directly the field's value like in `var v = $("#form [name='foo']").val ()`

Answer (score 5):

You should use id's or classes to speed up getting the value process.

ID version (assuming the input has id='foo')

```
var value1 = $('#foo').val();
```

Classes version (assuming the input has class='foo')

```
var value1 = $('.foo').val();
```